# Consistent template types

Tags: c++, templates

### Problem

Consider the following class

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
   T x;
};
```

Now, another class is templated like so:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class B
{
   protected:
      std::vector<U> arr;

   public:
      T get_x(unsigned int p) { return arr[p].x; }
};
```

I would like to access the field `A<T>::x` from within `B<T, A<T>>::get_x()` and return it unaltered (i.e., keep its type as `T`). My poor knowledge of templating says that this requires knowing the type andof `T` it should be one of the template parameters of `class B`. However, that makes it possible to declare something inconsistent, like `B<int, A<double>>`, and in general sounds like an unnecessary repetition.

### Questions

1. Is what I wrote an example of bad programming practice? How should this be written?
2. Is there a possibility of inferring the type `T` of `A<T>::x` and avoid two template types? It feels like a repetition, so I am not sure if there is a God-fearing, standard-abiding solution out there or not.

For what it is worth, I am using GCC 4.6.2 with -std=c++0x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest an approach adopted by the Standard Library. Define a nested type.

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
   typedef T value_type; //this is nested type to be used by B
   T x;
};

//this is another class added by me, just to demonstrate the genericity
template <typename T>
struct C
{
   typedef T value_type; //this is nested type to be used by B
   T x;
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
      typedef typename T::value_type value_type;  //get the nested type
   protected:
      std::vector<T> arr;

   public:
      value_type get_x(unsigned int p) { return arr[p].x; }
    //^^^^^^^^^ note this
};
```

Usage:

```
 B<A<int>> ba;    //'>>' if C++11, otherwise use '> >' (separate them by space)
 B<C<double>> bc; //works for C class template as well
```

Comment: Oh, that's why boost defines the template type this way! Awesome insight, thanks!

Comment: we could have used template template parameter as second type parameter to solve the issue , couldn't we? or we have only this way?

Comment: @user411102: If you use template template parameter, then probably, you will use `B<A, int>` instead of `B<A<int>>`. Yes, you can do that as well.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Your method is awesome though :)